# How do I build OpenCV with TBB on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to build OpenCV with TBB to enable multi-threading.

**Note:** I am able to build OpenCV-2.4.10 **without TBB** from source and then use the OpenCV Python bindings.

When I try a fresh install and building OpenCV with TBB installed the `WITH_TBB=ON` flag I am then **unable to** `import cv2` - I take this to mean something has gone wrong in the build process.

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
# Download, unpack and build TBB:
wget -O ~/tbb43_20150316oss_src.tgz --no-check-certificate https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/sites/default/files/software_releases/source/tbb43_20150316oss_src.tgz
tar -xvzf tbb43_20150316oss_src.tgz
cd tbb43_20150316oss
make tbb CXXFLAGS="-DTBB_USE_GCC_BUILTINS=1 -D__TBB_64BIT_ATOMICS=0"


# Build OpenCV:
cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON  \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

make -j4
```

Comment: If you want help, you really need to post the errors you are getting. Both from the build system (if there are any) and from Python.

Comment: where do you copy the TBB files after building them so that cmake can find them?

Comment: @flat Where are those supposed to be copied ? .so file and header files ? I'm following the same path. I was able to build tbb from source but it seems with_tbb flag in cmake is not effective. It's not able to find tbb.

Answer (score 1):

Just for others looking for solution for the same problem, I got success just asking for the cmake utility for build TBB for me:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_TBB=ON (more options) ..
```

After that, cmake downloaded TBB and I got something like:

```
Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9003)
```

in my cmake output. I'm running a Raspbian Jessie environment with Pixel. Hope this helps.